# Pre-fetch i18next translation files based on current route

Tags: react-i18next

I'm using `React-i18next` with `react-router`. Each route of my app, has a unique i18n namespace.

When the user is at a specific route, how can I pre-fetch translation files to optimise the user's page subsequent navigation?

Answer (score 0):

If your translations are split into multiple namespaces (and each namespace == 1 or more routes), then you can use the i18next API to pre-load namespaces as follows:

```
i18next
  .loadNamespaces(['myNamespace1', 'myNamespace2'])
  .then(() => {});
```

See https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#loadnamespaces

**Caveats**

- loadNamespaces will only load translations for the currently selected language
- Calling loadNamespaces multiple times, will use a cached result.

**Where to invoke?**

i18next is a singleton by default (unless you call `i18next.createInstance`), so you can import it into a module that listens for route changes and call `loadNamespaces` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the method mentioned by @Learner but the problem is the react components get rendered before the namespaces are loaded.

I have added a suspense component but it is getting used when I call
withTranslation([ns1, ns2])(Component)

and not
i18n.loadNamespaces([ns1, ns2]) in history.listen()

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.